# Getting last consecutive number of occurrences

Tags: postgresql

I need to find the **last number of consecutive rows** where the status is 'YES', ordering by date_created.

[image: example]

In this case, the number of consecutive rows would be **2**.

How can this be achieved in Postgres?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could check for the latest status<>YES and then select all newer rows, something like this:

```
select COUNT(1)
from table_a a
where a.status = 'YES'
and a.date_created >= (select max(date_created) from table_a b where b.status <> 'YES')
```